# Modify for database removes item

Tags: c#, database, dns, wmi

So I am trying to update all IP addresses in a database for the Microsoft DNS server and here is my code

```
internal bool UpdateIPFromDns(string oldIP, string newIP)
{
    try
    {
        string Query = ("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType WHERE RecordData = '" + oldIP + "'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, new ObjectQuery(Query));
        ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject wmiZone in col)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updating: " + (String)wmiZone.Properties["OwnerName"].Value + " To -> " + newIP);
            ManagementBaseObject mgmtParams = null;
            mgmtParams = wmiZone.GetMethodParameters("Modify");
            mgmtParams["IPAddress"] = newIP;
            wmiZone.InvokeMethod("Modify", mgmtParams, null);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error: " + ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

for sometimes it seems to work fine and other times it print out that it's updated the item (like it is supposed to), but when I refresh the database itself it has actually removed all those items and i'm not sure why it is doing this.

EDIT:

Ok so I have worked out when its deleting the items

So in the database we start with

```
Example.com->
example.com 1.1.1.1
t1.example.com 1.1.1.1
t2.example.com 2.3.4.5

test.com->
test.com 1.1.1.1
t1.test.com 2.3.4.5
t2.test.com 1.1.1.1
```

If I run the update on 1.1.1.1 and update it to 2.3.4.5 it updates so now the database looks like this

```
Example.com->
example.com 2.3.4.5
t1.example.com 2.3.4.5
t2.example.com 2.3.4.5

test.com->
test.com 2.3.4.5
t1.test.com 2.3.4.5
t2.test.com 2.3.4.5
```

Now if I was to run it again updating 2.3.4.5 to 2.3.4.5 it then removes all items with the IP 2.3.4.5

But I am not sure why its doing this

P.S I am not very experienced with WMI, so if I am doing something wrong there, let me know

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but just as a comment... it's generally frowned upon to use SELECT * in code, you should specify the exact columns you want to return. You'll always know in your code what you're getting, whereas the database can change significantly over time and return a lot more than you need.

Comment: @swinkel this is WMI the OP is using..

Comment: @swinkel thanks, but for when I was testing I was trying to work out what columns it had which is why I had the * but I will change it over now.

Comment: It has removed all the items enumerated in the foreach loop? Or some? Or all A records in your DNS server?

Comment: @Greg it either works flawlessly or it will remove all a records

Comment: instead of getting all confused with single quotes and double quotes in your string Query = change it to =
`string Query =  string.Format("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_AType WHERE RecordData = {0}", oldIP);`

Comment: Try and validate on the mgmtParams to be sure you have a modify and not a remove/delete. Also, make sure the new address is a valid one (`trim()`), so that the DNS service doesn't do something unexpected on bad input. But if some runs fully end in disaster, a bad ipaddress or two probably isn't the problem.

Comment: @Greg Check the post again , I have worked out what and when its doing it, but now im not sure why it is

Comment: Ha-ha, MS doesn't quite call it a bug. Their tone is pretty much "as designed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the implementation, per Microsoft, does exactly what they programmed it to do: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979609. (I had a feeling the server was doing something weird and that you had the WMI right). So you probably already built this in by now, but you need to skip the update if the old address equals the new address. Given that WMI is pretty expensive, that's a good idea anyway.